# iReport Hindi spelling mistake after pdf generation

Tags: pdf, itext

I added `Mangal.ttf` in `ireport` and `exported` jar file to all the required folders.I also change the properties such as:

1. 'pdf font name is now depricated': Mangal
2. checked pdf embedded
3. 'pdf encoding':Identity-H (Unicode with horizontal writing)

For example:

After generating pdf दिनांक becomes daniank(in hindi) PLEASE HELP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iReport uses iText to generate the PDF and iText doesn't support (yet, soon to change) Indic languages.